# Import Javascript library into CakePHP with CSS and imgs

Tags: javascript, cakephp

How would I import an entire JS library, with associated CSS and IMG files into CakePHP?

I'm trying to get **[jQuery.Gantt Chart](https://github.com/taitems/jQuery.Gantt)** into my project.

I've tried splitting it up into the three folders to conform with Cake's structure but there are so many js files and references that need to be fixed - I can't get the tool to work once I meddle around with it. Is there an easier way to import this into CakePHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a folder in your webroot.

Example:

```
/webroot/jquery-gantt/
```

Then, when you call it's js (or css), just make sure to start with a `/`.

```
echo $this->Html->script('/jquery-ganett/whatever.js');
```

There are many cases where it just doesn't make sense to break apart groups of files like that and is not a big deal to just keep them together.

Comment: Hi Dave, I tried this but it won't work.. I have this in my header: `echo $this->Html->script('/js_plugins/gantt.chart/js/jquery.fn.gantt.min.js');` but when I view the source on Chrome, it's pointing to `http://localhost/project02/js_plugins/gantt.chart/js/` which when visited throws a missing controller error.

Comment: @Chronix3 - Then there's something wrong w/ your CakePHP setup and is unrelated to this specific question.  (or the file you're pointing to doesn't actually exist).  What you're asking is something I do on a 3-4 times a day basis, and my answer IS correct.

Comment: @Chronix3 - Make sure modrewrite is on?

Comment: This is driving me insane.. :(

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   
RewriteEngine on
   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js_plugins/(.*)
RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

</IfModule>`

That's my .htaccess, trying to exclude the `js_plugins` folder but its not working.

Comment: Oh wow, silly me. When I read `webroot` I took it literally as the root of my project and not the folder in the CakePHP structure... It all works well now! Thanks Dave :)